# onmouseover event not working

Tags: javascript, html

Im making a simple hud that supposed to show itself when your mouse is on the main panel.
For some reason the onmouseover and out not working. When I click inspect element in the browser on the panel it shows me the html tag. I know that the listeners were created, again from looking at the inspect element in the browser.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
    <LINK href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainpanel" class="notselectable">
        <div id="top">
            <img src="icons/white/open.png" style="float:right" class="btnMedia" />
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
            <center>
                <img src="icons/white/pre.png" class="leftandright btnMedia" />
                <img src="icons/white/play.png" class="leftandright btnMedia" />
                <img src="icons/white/next.png" class="leftandright btnMedia" />
            </center>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
<script>
    var panel = document.getElementById("mainpanel");
    var top = document.getElementById("top");
    var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");
    //alert("script")
    panel.onmouseover = function() {
        alert("in")
        top.display = "block";
        bottom.display = "block";
    }
    panel.onmouseout = function() {
        alert("out")
        top.display = "none";
        bottom.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `top.style.display = "block";` Make this change everywhere

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy nothing changed :O

Answer (score 1):

There are two things wrong in your code.

1. Missing `style` when manipulating with CSS values
2. And `top` is a [reserved keyword](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp) in JavaScript and it's tricky to use it as an variable

This works:

```js
var panel = document.getElementById("mainpanel");
var top2 = document.getElementById("top");
var bottom = document.getElementById("bottom");

panel.onmouseover = function() {
    top2.style.display = "block";
    bottom.style.display = "block";
}
panel.onmouseout = function() {
    top2.style.display = "none";
    bottom.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
#mainpanel {
  background: #faa;
  height: 100vh;
}
#top, #bottom {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Hello World!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mainpanel" class="notselectable">
        <div id="top">
          I am top!
        </div>
        <div id="bottom">
          I am bottom!
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```